# Android | Data received from device is not the same as sent

Tags: android, inputstream

I try to receive data from custom device. Here's my part of code responsible for that :

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    try {
                        final byte[] read = input.readLine().getBytes();

                        if (read != null) {
                            cnt++;
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            for (byte b : read) {
                                sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                            }
                            Log.e(TAG, "run: " + cnt + " " + sb.toString());

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

It works but the problem is - most part of the data is ok but for example instead of ff byte I'm receiving CB 99 :

Here's what I'm receiving :

C2 96 6D 39 02 C2 8C 7D 39 01 15 C2 8D 39 01 C4 BD C2 8D 39 02 C3 B4 7E 39 02 60 6D 39 02 C4 87 7D 39 01 66 C2 8D 39 01 C3 89 C2 8D 39 02 40 7E 39 02 C2 96 6D 39 02 C5 99 7D 39 01 0C C2 8D 39 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 CB 99 3C 2F 72 61 77 3E 3C 65 6E 64 5F 63 68 3E 74 72 75 65 3C 2F 65 6E 64 5F 63 68 3E

And here's what device is sending :

[image]

I don't know if I make myself clear, if not, please write me - I will try to explain everything :) Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: It would help to know how you are sending data, and from where to where. Is this data just sent over a socket?

Comment: Yes, it's a medical device. It sends data over a socket to mobile app.

Comment: Are the two data excerpts exactly comparable? Because there are a lot more differences than "cb 99" vs "ff". I suppose `input` is a `BufferedReader`. First I would suggest that calling `readLine()` to get a `String` and then calling `getBytes()` is not the same as getting the actual bytes off the line. There is an implied conversion in `getBytes()` according to the default charset on the system. You need to show more code, like where the `BufferedReader` is initialized and more about the `InputStream`.